# Approval workflow using SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have a workflow task that is a parallel task to multiple approves. They should all receive the task at the same time and any one of them should be able to approve it. But what I am encountering is when one approver, approves or rejects the task, it sends an email to everyone saying the task has been cancelled. I want to know if I can stop this email from being sent:

Attached:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the drop-down and select `WaiveCancelationEmail` to `Yes` in order to stop sending the cancellation emails.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike for prompt respond. Can you clarify a little bit more . I attached the screen shot.

Comment: I edited my answer because this is a 2013 workflow.